# Return strings in array that begin with the initial passed

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a .txt file which has data for states as given below:

```
AL,Alab,4860
AK,Alas,7415
AZ,Ariz,6908
AR,Arka,2988
```

I have made a function which counts how many states there are that start with the initial passed as such:

```
public int CInitial(char initial) {
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) { //states is an array which includes all states present in the .txt file
        String testString = states[i].getName(); // getName gets the name of the states present in the .txt file
        char[] stringToCharArray = testString.toCharArray();
        for (char output : stringToCharArray) {
            if(initial == output) {
                total++;        
            }

        }   

    }
        return total; 
}
```

This would return the number 4 if "A" is passed and 0 if any other initial is passed as there are 4 states that begin with the letter "A".

Now how can I create a new function that passes a character and returns the name of all the states that begin with that character? For Instance this is the initial return type needed for this, however I'm having troubles starting this. Is the process identical to the *countStatesCountByInitial* function I created?

```
public State[] CByInitial(char initial) {
        return new State[] {}; //to be completed    
    }
```

Comment: Include the full definition of your `State` class.

Comment: there is no need to add the [tag:eclipse] tag if your question is not specifically related to a problem with eclipse itself.

Comment: `for (char output : stringToCharArray) {` why are you looping over the whole string if you only want to check the first char? hint: use String#startswith

Comment: "returns the name of all the states that begin with that character" - then your method should look like this: `public String[] getSomething(char initial)`

Comment: DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself), the second method returning `State[]` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be very similar to the `countStatesCountByInitial`. The main difference is each time you find a match, you want to add the state into the array. Since we don't know the size of the array beforehand, we may want to use a `List` instead.

```
public State[] getStatesCountByInitial(char initial) {
    ArrayList<State> found = new ArrayList<>();

    // this is the same as before
    for(int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        String testString = states[i].getName();
        char[] stringToCharArray = testString.toCharArray();
        for (char output : stringToCharArray) {
            if(initial == output) {
            // except here when you find a match, you add it into the list
            found.add(states[i]);        
            }
        }   
    }

    // return as array
    return found.toArray(new State[found.size()]);
}
```

As suggested by Patrick, we can avoid using `List` by using `countStatesCountByInitial` to initialize the size of the states.

```
public State[] getStatesCountByInitial(char initial) {
    int matchSize = countStatesCountByInitial(initial);
    States[] found = new States[matchSize];
    int foundIndex = 0;

    // this is the same as before
    for(int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        String testString = states[i].getName();
        char[] stringToCharArray = testString.toCharArray();
        for (char output : stringToCharArray) {
            if(initial == output) {
                // except here when you find a match, you add it into the array
                found[foundIndex] = states[i];
                foundIndex++;
            }
        }   
    }

    // return the array
    return found;
}
```

Comment: or rather than introducing the concept of lists when learning arrays, you could use `countStatesCountByInitial` to get the size of the array.

Comment: `for (char output : stringToCharArray) {` why are you looping over the whole string if you only want to check the first char? hint: use String#startswith

Comment: @Magdrop your original answer actually worked instead of this one

Comment: @Magdrop also, instead of return I tried printing the output but it has a gibberish output as [LstateInformation.State;@5f4da5c3 not quite sure what's happening?

Comment: @Utsav, that's the default `toPrint()` result of a java object.  If you need to print the `States` object, you have to override `States`' `toPrint()` method with your own print out.

Comment: @Utsav, I edit the answer to include both options there.  If you want, you can tell me what failed on the second one so I can fix it.

Comment: This code is wrong. You should not loop over each char, because state will match if *any* character is the same as initial.

Comment: @Bohemian, I'm reusing Utsav original code assuming that it works as intended.  I believe there are comments about that already on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can done both operations simply by one method.

```
public static ArrayList<State> getStatesCountByInitial(char initial) {
        ArrayList selectedStates = new ArrayList<State>();
        for(int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            if(states.charAt(0) == initial){
                selectedStates.add(states[i]);
            }
        }
        return selectedStates;
}
```

This method will return a arraylist.
If you want to get the count, call this method and get the size of the array.

```
ArrayList<State> statesNew = getStatesCountByInitial('A');
int count = statesNew.size();
```